# How do I reproduce the [FromUri] behavior for complex parameters in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm currently creating a new API but I need to receive complex parameters by URL.  I can't easily change those parameters without risking errors on other systems.

I'm using .Net Core 2.1 and since [FromUri] does not exist, I had to use [FromQuery].  The problem is that it won't fill complex parameters.  I know it's not a basic feature of .NET Core but searching around I found solutions but none seems to work.  I tried a clean project and have the same problem.

Example URL : https://localhost:44337/api/values?simple=true&foo[0][value]=1&foo[0][name]=bar&foo[1][value]=2&foo[1][name]=ultra%20bar

Using the basic Core API template from Visual Studio 2017, I only changed the controller.

```
public class FooParameter
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get([FromQuery]bool simple, [FromQuery]FooParameter[] foos)
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

The result is :

```
simple = True
foos = Length 0 Array of FooParameter
```

I tried

- Using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim : Nothing
- Using a custom ModelBinder : It seems to think foo[0][value] is the entire key of the parameter
- Using dynamic or object as types : Empty objects
- Reducing to one level "&foo[value]=1&foo[name]=bar" instead (for testing) : contains null, null

I could just parse everything myself with Request.Query, but it too thinks "foo[0][value]" is the parameter key and I got a huge list of possibilities to take count of.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something completely obvious but I just can't find anything.  My only restriction is I can't touch the query string format.

Comment: Hi, I faced the same problem, when I wanted to send a list or a table of values as url parameters.I think it will always generate errors. What I recommend is to translate the link from this : "https://localhost:44337/api/values?simple=true&foo[0][value]=1&foo[0][name]=bar&foo[1][value]=2&foo[1][name]=ultra%20bar" to this : "https://localhost:44337/api/values?simple=true&foos=1&foos=bar&foos=2&foos=ultra%20bar". This link is acceptable for the controller method as a table "FooParamter[] foos".

Comment: @mehdizahrane I thought so, but like I said I can't change the URL without losing my sanity.  Long story short, I got some stuff here that was converted from something like Fortran to C++ with an automatic script then wrapped in a managed C++ then wrapped in C# so just looking at that code is enough to roll in a ball crying for the sweet relief of death.

Comment: _Using a custom ModelBinder : It seems to think foo[0][value] is the entire key of the parameter_ That's the **correct behavior**. HTTP/HTML isn't aware of objects, arrays etc. so `foo[0][value]`. It's totally up to the server application to interpret these as keys or object structures.

Comment: For example: `param=value&param=value2&param=value3`. This is to be interpreted as 3 parameters with 3 different values. **HOW** the server/framework interprets that is completely up to frameworks implementation. ASP.NET Core will bind that happily to an `string[]` array. PHP on the other side will treat it as a single parameter and only one of the 3 values will be taken unless you pass send `param[]=value&param[]=value2&param[]=value3` or `param[0]=value&param[1]=value2&param[3]=value3`. For HTML/HTTP, its just 3 keys with 3 values

Comment: @Tseng So if I understand correctly my choices are :
1) Make a proxy that reformats the query in a supported format and sending it to the API
2) Curse the .Net Core and migrate to Framework
3) Bite the bullet and code my own parser to simulate the correct interpretation like [FromUri] did.

Comment: I just tried [FromQuery]string[] foo with ?foo=bar&foo=bigbar... length 0

Comment: "complex parameters"   The best you will get are strings.

Comment: Yea. ASP.NET Core is made to be flexible, that's why its very extendable. The cleanest way may be the custom binder (which you could also identify via an custom attribute). You can also use the UrlRewrite middleware to bring it into a more appropriate format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: @Tseng There must be something else wrong, even string[] returns an empty array.

Comment: @JamesMcGrath Works fine for me, though only when the `[ApiController]` is omitted. Not sure why that behaviour. An implication when using ApiControllerAttribute is that the model will be validated automatically and it fails even on https://example.com:44331/api/values/1?foo=bar&foo=baz

Comment: May be related to [Array or List in query string does not get parsed](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712), which means won't be fixed until ASP.NET Core 2.2. Try removing the [ApiController]  attribute as a work around or setting the compatibility to 2.0 as mentioned in the github issue via `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_0);`

Comment: Or try `[FromQuery(Name="foo")]string[] foo` but this didn't worked in my test project

Comment: @Tseng I just got the string array to work by using Get([FromQuery]CustomParams args) and setting string[] in that class.  Almost got foo[bar] working too that way.

Comment: What works though is `?foo[0].value1=test&foo[0].value2=test&foo[1].value1=test&foo[1].value2=test`  on `MyClass[]` with two properties Value1 and Value2, but requires a slight rewrite of the url or `?foo[0][value1]=test&foo[0][value2]=test&foo[1][value1]=test&foo[1][value2]=test` if you bind to `Dictionary<String,String>[]` (but lose model validation and strong typing)

Comment: Have a look on how `CollectionModelBinder` is implemented in https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs and try to make your custom binder, maybe the most flexible way

Comment: For the moment I managed to get ?foo[bar]=val&foo[id]=1&foo[bar]=val2&foo[id]=2 to return {"foo":{"bar":["val","val2"],"id":[1,2]}} by using [FromQuery(Name = "[bar]")]

Comment: @Tseng Yeah, I'll work on that and post my fix as an answer when I'm done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way the parameters must be cast so the HTML arrays are correctly loaded.  It's not entirely dynamic but it works for my needs.

You need to use the Name attribute on FromQuery to be able to get objects.

```
public class FooBar
{
    [FromQuery(Name = "[bar]")]
    public string bar { get; set; }
    [FromQuery(Name = "[id]")]
    public int id { get; set; }
}
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<FooBar> Get([FromQuery(Name = "foo")]FooBar[] foo)
{
    return foo;
}
```

This will take ?foo[0][bar]=val&foo[0][id]=1&foo[1][bar]=val2&foo[1][id]=2 and return [{"bar":"val","id":1},{"bar":"val2","id":2}]

You can keep [ApiController] and no need to make a custom ModelBinder.

Comment: why are you overriding the default name, you should be able to bind to Foo[0].Bar

Comment: @johnny5 You mean like Get([FromQuery]FooBar[] foo) ?  It doesn't work, I get an empty array.

Comment: Ok, you are right. Didn't try Get([FromQuery(Name = "foo")]FooBar[] foo).  I'll correct the answer.

Comment: I meant from your querystring

Comment: @johnny5 I can't change the querystring format. I'm stuck with the vanilla HTML form way of doing it